# Google Earth API fails to load placemark with custom icon

Tags: javascript, apache, google-earth-plugin

At one point I was able to load custom placemark icons into the Google Earth JavaScript API; however, sometime in the last few months, something has changed.

If I add a marker in the google domain it seems to work... but if I use another icon from the internet it fails.

I followed the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/placemarks?hl=de-DE#custom) from the documentation and I still get nothing.

```
// Define a custom icon.
var icon = earth.createIcon('');
icon.setHref('http://www.jcsda.noaa.gov/images/arrowDown.jpg');
var style = earth.createStyle(''); //create a new style
style.getIconStyle().setIcon(icon); //apply the icon to the style
placemark.setStyleSelector(style); //apply the style to the placemark
```

For the sake of clarity I have made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44Ra3/8/) illustrating the problem.

Any thoughts on where I am going wrong?

### UPDATE

Last night when I made [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44Ra3/8/) the icon failed to load... this morning when I checked it has spontaneously started working for some icons.

Interestingly, it's still not working in my application.

I am using an Apache web server and I have some security in place (using .htaccess file) requiring a username and password... this has been active for months, but could it now be prevent Google Earth from accessing the icons even though I am logged in?

Answer (score 0):

Is your page https is could be a browser mixed content http/https issue